# How do I make document.getElementById('id').value return a number not a string in Javascript

Tags: javascript, string, numbers, getelementbyid

I am making a form for users to input number and then trying to display the sum.
But the `document.getElementById('someid').value` is returning a string. And hence my add function is concatenating the strings instead of adding them as number. How do I solve it. Sorry for such a basic question.

```
//Script
function add(){
var a = document.getElementById('num1').value;
var b = document.getElementById('num2').value;
return a + b;
}
console.log(add());
//HTML
<p> Input 2 numbers to add</p>
<input type="number" id="num1"/>
<input type="number" id="num2"/>
<input type="submit" value="Add" onclick="add()">
```

Comment: there's nothing as `<p1>` tag.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. Edited to <p>

Answer (score 4):

Try to use **`parseInt`**. This function returns number

Answer (score 4):

You have three options.

1. parseInt

please please add the base 10 parsing to it, since you save the engine from trying to guess which base it should parse the integer to.

> return parseInt(a, 10) + parseInt(b, 10);

2. Coercion

the method i prefer is coercing String type to number type by simply wrapping the string in a number constructor

> return Number(a) + Number(b);

3.unary plus

unary plus is the fastest and preferred way of converting something into a number. but Number(a) is much more readable in my opinion.

> return +a + +b

Note: do not copy bad code from people parsing integers without giving it a base for parsing.

Answer (score 1):

```
var a = parseInt(document.getElementById('num1').value);
```

ref link: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp

Answer (score 1):

You should prepend it with`+` since they are **strings** and not **numbers**.

*Try this:*

```
function add(){
    var a = document.getElementById('num1').value;
    var b = document.getElementById('num2').value;
    var x = +a + +b;
    return x;
}
```

or, simply:

```
var a = parseInt(document.getElementById('num1').value);
var b = parseInt(document.getElementById('num2').value);
var x = a + b;
```

*Modify your code instead:*

```
<html>
<body>
<p>Input 2 numbers to add</p>
<input type="number" id="num1"/>
<input type="number" id="num2"/>
<input type="submit" value="Add" onclick="add()">
<p id="result"></p>
<script>
function add(){
    var a = document.getElementById('num1').value;
    var b = document.getElementById('num2').value;
    var x = +a + +b;
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = x;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to tell javascript that you want to work with numbers instead of strings.
So instead of

```
function add(){
  var a = document.getElementById('num1').value;
  var b = document.getElementById('num2').value;
  return a + b;
}
```

you can use

```
function add(){
  var a = document.getElementById('num1').value + 0;
  var b = document.getElementById('num2').value + 0;
  return a + b;
}
```

or

```
function add(){
  var a = parseInt(document.getElementById('num1').value);
  var b = parseInt(document.getElementById('num2').value);
  return a + b;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`parseInt(document.getElementById("id").value)` For integers
`parseFloat(document.getElementById("id").value)` For floating point number so decimals